# CSS for Drag & Drop UX

Tags: css, angularjs, debugging, drag-and-drop

*I should preface this by saying my CSS skills are rather lacking.*

## problem

I am utilizing an angular drag & drop directive - [angular-drop-and-drop-lists](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists). When I switch it over to be a horizontal list where I'm trying to drag boxes, the `dndPlaceholder` element (i.e. the grey box) doesn't style like I want it to.

#### plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/1BuPv6Rr4HoaNgyRzB1t?p=preview

#### `placeholder` css

```
.simple-demo ul[dnd-list] .dndPlaceholder {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ddd;
    min-height: 42px;
    min-width: 100px;
    margin: 1px;
}
```

#### screenshot

[image: screenshot]

---

## desired resolution

What I want is for the `dndPlaceholder` to be vertically aligned with the other elements in the list. The Red square marks the desired location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `vertical-align: bottom;` to your `.dndPlaceholder` style rules.

Comment: well gee.... about the only thing I didn't try hahaha.  Thanks.  Here is the updated Plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/c8AUlbsyqUGlSIrq5YgK?p=preview

Comment: Here is a followup question: why do the existing items already align to the bottom without explicitly stating so? I have yet to look into the code of the library but I assume that he's doing something on the dynamically generated placeholder element that's not exposed normally.

Comment: The default value for the `vertical-align` property is `baseline` which aligns items based on the baseline of their text. This works great for the tabs to start with because they all have one line of text, meaning all of their baselines are in the same place. The placeholder, however, has no text content, so it's baseline value will be calculated differently, causing it to be out of alignment with the other elements

Comment: Thank you for the concise explanation.  That makes sense when put that way.